# How to calcuate amount of electricity required for cooling x watts of equipment in DC?

Tags: power, cooling

I have a rack which totals 8000 watts, now based upon this number I want to calculate the amount of electricity that goes into cooling the heat dissipated from this rack?

Is there any calculation, I can use.

Comment: How efficient is your cooling?

Comment: I'm thinking the rule of thumb is on the order of 3-4x, but there are a lot of variables.  You can, of course, "cheat" a bit and just use a fan to exhaust the heat outdoors, if the outside air that replaces it is cool and dry enough.

Comment: [LiquidCool Solutions](http://www.liquidcoolsolutions.com/) has what is probably the most efficient cooling setup.  Unfortunately, their site is a little too "cute" to allow one to find any hard numbers without digging.

Comment: Too many variables.  For example.  Fans to cool, versus a liquid cooling rig which uses an electric pump *and* fans.  Now, what if you added Peltier chips beneath all of the heatsinks, and you did that in conjunction with a liquid cooling rig.  All three of those options would use different amounts of electricity, and all three would cool to different degrees.